# Iptables rule for dropping VM packets in Qemu

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, iptables, qemu

I am trying to drop packets for a tap interface connected VM, but it does not work.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i 553d1a58350ea -s 172.16.0.206 -j DROP
ping 172.16.4.119 # Works
```

My QEMU uses that, it is invoked as follows: (omitted non-related args)

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -net nic,model=virtio,netdev=net0 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=553d1a58350ea,script=no,downscript=no
```

I created the tap device by my hand connected it to a Open vSwitch bridge. Why is my rule not working? If I just use the same rule for another interface on the host, it works and blocks connections.

The tap interface does not have an IP address itself, but I can see the all the traffic with tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -i 553d1a58350ea
```

Is it releted to tap device not having an IP address?

Answer (score 0):

What about a forward rule in the filter table?

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s (source ip) -o tap0 -DROP
```

`-o` sets the outgoing network interface for a rule and may only be used with OUTPUT and FORWARD chains in the filter table, and the POSTROUTING chain in the nat and mangle tables. This parameter's options are the same as those of the incoming network interface parameter (`-i`).